# Using IsotopeJS on list items within a Vue 3 template

Tags: vue.js, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use isotopeJS filtering but the list container is inside my Vue3 template. I've tried to use v-pre to tell the renderer to ignore the list as it doesn't need any Vue3 rendering. Also, I've tried using the onUpdated hook to hopefully do the filtering after re-rendering but the filtering only works when I remove the list container out of the Vue template.

```
<div id="app">
  <!-- checkbox filters that are rendered using Vue 3. These filters are used to filter isotope list -->

  <div class="row row-cols-3" id="list-container" v-pre>
    <!-- list items.. i don't want vue to touch these but ideally want it to sit between checkboxes and pagination -->
  </div>

  <!-- pagination html that is rendered using Vue 3 -->
</div>
```

Here is my setup() function:

```
const app = createApp({
  setup() {

    // ...

    // init isotope
    const $grid = $('#list-container')

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log("onMounted");
      $grid.isotope({
        itemSelector: '[data-list-item]',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
      })
    })

    onUpdated(() => {
      console.log("onUpdated");
      setTimeout(() => $grid.isotope({
        filter: function () {
          // filtering logic
        }
      }), 200);
    })

    return {
      // ...
    }
  }
})
```

The `onMounted` and `onUpdated` is output to the console when I expect them to but nothing happens with the isotope filtering.

However, if I move the isotope list container out of the app template, it works:

```
<div id="app">
  <!-- checkbox filters that are rendered using Vue 3. These filters are used to filter isotope list -->

  <!-- pagination html that is rendered using Vue 3 -->
</div>

<div class="row row-cols-3" id="list-container">
  <!-- list items.. -->
</div>
```

But this isn't ideal, as I want the list to sit between the checkboxes and pagination.

The only solution I've found in the past is 2 different Vue apps:

```
<div id="app1">
  <!-- checkbox filters that are rendered using Vue 3. These filters are used to filter isotope list -->
</div>

<div class="row row-cols-3" id="list-container">
  <!-- list items.. i don't want vue to touch these but ideally want it to sit between checkboxes and pagination -->
</div>

<div id="app2">
  <!-- pagination html that is rendered using Vue 3 -->
</div>
```

.. but it makes it more complex as I have to share properties between apps. Would be must simpler to have it all under one app. I'm wondering if it's something to do with Vue detecting a change to the DOM, and "correcting" it all very quickly that it looks like nothing is happening..  but this is just a theory. I tried to use onUpdated to hopefully fire after any such rendering.

Comment: v-pre means an element won't be affected by template compilation, but this doesn't mean it's not touched by Vue at all. Don't access DOM in setup. I'd expect it to work if you use $('#list-container') in onMounted

Comment: Thanks. Actually, what worked just now was defining the isotope element as `const elem = ref(null)` then using a template ref for when the dom was ready `<div .. ref="elem">` then onMounted declaring the iso object